# API with Passport Validation and Error Handling

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

Im having some issues regarding validating the requests,  laravel Route api.php is acting like Route web.php.

My api routes is:

```
Route::post('login', 'PassportController@login');
Route::post('register', 'PassportController@register');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    //USERS
    Route::get('get-details', 'UserController@getDetails');
});
```

I configured all good passport has the documentation told me, and works fine, but now im testing my request where is not included the token to validate and error handling.

My Route:

```
 http://localhost:8000/api/get-details
```

My User Controller:

```
 public function getDetails()
    {

        if(!Auth::check())
        {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorised'], 401);
        }
        //Get Auth User
        $user = Auth::user();

        //Return 404 if user not found
         if(is_null($user)){
             return response()->json(null,404);
         }
         return response()->json($user, 200);
    }
```

Than using Postman or other tool, i added my route iwthout the token to than case if the token is not included give me a json error message. But insted gives me this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.
```

And i notice the issue was in the Midleware Authenticate.php:

```
 protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

Where 'expectsJson' is giving me false. How can i resolve the issue? Many examples i see online tells overwriding the Request base or commenting the return route login, but this is not a solution for me since in my case im having in the same App the API routes where my mobile app communicates with it, and then ill have a web backend to manage the information.

Can someone advise me how to solve the issue?

Comment: You need `$request->expectsJson()` to return true so that you are not redirected from an api request: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9f313ce9bb5ad49a06ae78d33fbdd1c92a0e21f6/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.php#L42

Comment: Yes, your right, but i wish also to handle case the use didnt add the json content type at the header, how would i handle?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You should be able to specify whatever request headers you want, since you are the one initiating the request?

Comment: Imagine that im calling a api request, but for some reason i forgot in my request using Guzzle to put has application/json, what will happen is that laravel with try to call the routelogin in a API call, and in this case it cant happen since is being made a API call, did you understand?

Comment: Right, so don't forget. Or create your own middleware.